# Least square using orthogonal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, numerical-methods, least-squares, orthogonal-polynomials

I have obtained some orthogonal polynomials, using Gram orthogonal process, and the next question says, using them (O.P.) obtain the least square approximation of second degree for $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ on $[0,1]$.

How can i approximate it when it is already of lower degree than second degree ?
Like in Chebyshev case I used $$P_{n-1}=P_n-a_n\bar{T}_n$$

But how do I obtain for the above part, given that I have obtianed orthogonal polynomial as
$$P_0=1 $$ $$P_1=x-\frac12$$ $$P_2=x^2-x+\frac16$$

Comment: You need to compute the dot products of the given function with your orthogonal polynomials. Make sure to normalize them as well.

Answer (score 1):

First we construct a set of orthogonal polynomials on the interval $[0,1]$ obtaining with kernel $1$, the polynomials

$$
\cases{
p_0(x) = -1\\
p_1(x) = 2 \sqrt{3} x-\sqrt{3}\\
p_2(x) = -6 \sqrt{5} x^2+6 \sqrt{5} x-\sqrt{5}
}
$$

after that, with $f(x) = x^{\frac 32}$ we obtain

$$
c_k = \left< f, p_k\right> = \int_0^1 f(x)p_k(x)dx
$$

and finally

$$
f(x)\approx \sum_{k=0}^{k=2} c_k p_k(x)
$$

or

$$
f(x)\approx -\frac{2 \left(-6 \sqrt{5} x^2+6 \sqrt{5} x-\sqrt{5}\right)}{21 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{6}{35} \sqrt{3} \left(2 \sqrt{3} x-\sqrt{3}\right)+\frac{2}{5}
$$

Follows a plot showing in blue $f(x)$ and in red the corresponding approximation

[image]

Comment: i dont understand, then what is the use of the orthogonal polynomials i have obtained ? P_0,1,2 i have obtained already ... so why aer you obtaining again , when the question says you need to approximate using that only... why u are generating new things ?

Comment: If you already have the polynomials as it seems, you can now perform the calculations as presented. Don't forget to normalize the polynomials.

Comment: can you please do it , i dont understand what to do still ??? by taking my polynomials .. no need to plot graph... i can do that

Comment: To normalize the polynomials, you should do $\bar p_k(x) = \frac{p_k(x)}{\sqrt{\int_0^1 p_k(x)^2 dx}}$